# Visualizing German ALKIS LoD2/cityGML data in 3D map view QGIS 3.22

Tags: qgis, 3d, visualisation, citygml, building

I have a dataset containing all relevant information to build a 3D building (https://ldbv.bayern.de/produkte/3dprodukte/3d.html) with one layer containing roof information (incl. orientation and slope), walls and ground surface. The description says that data is stored in CityGML format, QGIS also detects the data as  MultiPolygonZ. However I can't display the roof polygons correctly in the 3D mapview as shown in this update by QGIS: https://media.ccc.de/v/bucharest-380-qgis-3d-current-state-and-future-plans#t=566 (from min 9:30) since it always appears flat. What is the right workflow for this?

This is a screenshot of all the fields included in the dataset:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Having only a quick look to the FOSS4G2019 session it seems that the QGIS visualization there was a LOD1 representation only (have a look at ca. 12:00).

The standadized roof types of the LOD2 building models can be visualized using other tools capable of this functionality.

Suggestions:

- [FKZ Viewer](https://www.iai.kit.edu/1302.php) of Karlsruhe Institute of Technology - stand alone
  tool for visualization only
- [3DCityDB WebMap Client](https://github.com/3dcitydb/3dcitydb-web-map) - needs a
  postgresql or oracle based spatial (and 3DCityGML enabled) database
- [FME](https://engage.safe.com/blog/2022/02/using-citygml-work-large-scale-3d-data/) - commercial GIS tool
- [hale Studio](https://wetransform.to/de/halestudio/) - used for INSPIRE compliant dataset generation but afak capable to vizualize CityGML when set up correctly
- ESRI Arcgis and/or CityEngine should be capable to visualize CityGML (also not tested by myself)

Also have a look to [TU Delft's](https://3d.bk.tudelft.nl/projects/geobim-benchmark/software.html) and the [citygml wiki](https://www.citygmlwiki.org/index.php?title=Freeware)
(where some of my suggestions originate from)